# bash: assign to an array in bash from a function called with the & control operator

Tags: arrays, bash, function

I'd like to know why this works:

```
arr=()
fun() { arr[$1]=$2; }
fun 1 2
echo ${arr[1]}
# echoes '2'
```

but this doesn't:

```
arr=()
fun() { arr[$1]=$2; }
fun 1 2 &
wait
echo ${arr[1]}
# echoes a blank line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running `fun` in the background in your second example, you run it in a subshell. Changes to the array made in the subshell are not visible to the parent shell, where you echo the value of `arr[1]`.

Comment: and the same thing would happen if you created any subprocess, eg: `(fun 1 2)` or `echo | fun 1 2`

Answer (score 0):

This can't work, as running the function asynchronously creates a new shell context, which can't modify the parent context's environment. This is much similar to pipes into control structures, where variables modified inside the control structure won't be modified in the parent outside the pipe.